# Changing/using multiple layouts within the same activity?

Tags: android, layout, view

I am new to android programming but have a pretty strong Java background.  I am working on creating a fairly simple game that involves progressing through various short "levels", and the whole thing is timed, the objective being to get the fastest time possible.  I put levels in quotations because they are very short, and mainly involve doing a few simple tasks (i.e. clicking a button) before progressing to the next one.  As a result instead of creating a different activity for each level, I decided to keep everything within one activity and when a user completes all of the tasks for one level, a different layout is set-up using the setContentView() method.  My problem is that every time I switch layouts, I need to reset my pointers to the buttons using findViewById() even though they are named the same.  If someone could explain why I need to do this that would be very helpful?  Also, as I am fairly new to android, perhaps I am not going about this in the most efficient way?  Any suggestions would be welcome and appreciated.

Also I think this is probably related, but I have a chronometer that I want to be persistent across the layouts?  I have seen in other questions that this is not possible across activities, but I wanted to check on the case of across layouts.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Edit: Thank you ania, viewflipper looks like the perfect solution

Edit: So after some experimenting with the ViewFlipper I have decided to use it for my project.  While it does not solve the issue of having to re-add the buttons with every new level(this I solved by giving each button a distinct name, even across all layouts), it did give me some nice animation effects as well as the convenience of using showNext and showPrevious methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)? It seems like perfect solution in this case.

Comment: After taking a look at ViewFlipper am I right in your idea/thinking that I would use this to basically cycle through layouts?  I haven't used this before, so any idea if it would solve the having to reset the buttons every time?

Comment: In ViewFlipper you can put many different views between which you can animate. It is the same as you are doing now. I don't know how you define buttons, are they in your layouts or is it constant thing on every of your layouts? If buttons are always there, you can but ViewFlipper and buttons in your layout. VF will switch between views but buttons will be there all the time. The same thing will work with chronometer.

Comment: Your buttons are not there after setContentView because this method creates new layout from xml file. You are expecting that if you defined buttons with have the same id nothing will change but after setContentView method your previous view object is not longer available for you(and your buttons with it) and new layout (view object) is created (with new buttons). Giving the same name don't change anything in this case, you still have to find your object again in new layout.

Comment: Oh okay, so I think the way that I am defining my buttons right now is through layouts (I create them in xml and then use findViewById, do I have that right?), but the main reason why I did this was because the buttons move around on the screen in every new layout, so while they still have the same background image, text, etc. they are in a different location.

Comment: As far as I know android - yes, that's the your problem - creating new layouts. I don't know your application but maybe you can just change background view and leave your buttons there - moving. So: create one layout, put there your buttons and ViewFlipper with many different views between which you can switch. Because I don't see your code it's hard to advice anything different/better.